# Competing versions of GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, pyqgis

This is confusing, and a question I've harvested from a duplicate, so let me start with my setup.

- OS: Windows 7 x64
- GIS Client 1: ArcGIS Desktop 10.5
- GIS Client 2: ArcGIS Pro 1.4
- GIS Client 3: Boundless Desktop 1.0 (QGIS 2.14)

**Background**

Many of the scripts I write, I try to keep open-source for those without a fancy ArcGIS license.  However, I can't set PyQGIS as my default system interpreter in my environment variables because it will break many of the tools in ArcMap.  So I have taken the approach of making ArcGIS's Python instance the system Python, and installing open-source libraries there (and using .pth files to pull in qgis.core functionality if I need it).  I am using Gohlke's precompiled GDAL wheel (32-bit) in this case.  I am operating under the assumption that this breaks the fewest amount of things.

**Problem**

I have multiple installs of GDAL, and the system seems to keep defaulting to one of them, ignoring any environment variables I set.

`C:\Program Files\GDAL` contains version **2.1.0** (64-bit).

`C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\osgeo` contains version **2.1.3** (32-bit).

`C:\Program Files\GDAL` appears nowhere in my user environment variables.

Instead, I have the variables:

`GDAL_DATA` pointing to `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\gdal`

and a variable called

`GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` pointing to `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\osgeo`.

`C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\osgeo` is in my `PATH`.

Yet, when I open a command prompt and type `ogrinfo --version` it does not give me 2.1.3 (the version in `PATH`) but rather 2.1.0 (the 64-bit version in `\Program Files\GDAL`, which is nowhere in `PATH`).

What gives?

**Answers that do not answer my question**

[How to force QGIS to use GDAL version?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212620/how-to-force-qgis-to-use-gdal-version)

[Unable to call GDAL functionalities from Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125179/unable-to-call-gdal-functionalities-from-python)

[How to add support for FileGDB (Esri file gdb API) driver in fiona?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-add-support-for-filegdb-esri-file-gdb-api-driver-in-fiona)

[GDAL version in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225410/gdal-version-in-qgis)

[Does Gohlke GDAL break Command-Line GDAL/OGR in Windoiws?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198289/does-gohlke-gdal-break-command-line-gdal-ogr-in-windoiws)

Comment: hmm, have you tried uninstalling then reinstalling arc? i have had very funky things happen to my environmental python variables when I downloaded gdal in the same folder as arcgis python

Comment: Type `set` inside the command line window. Apart from the `PATH` value, look also for `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`. If you use the OSGEO4W shell, kit sets its own environment variables. Not sure if Boundless does the same.

Comment: Do you have separate administrator and user accounts?

Comment: workaround : give the full path of your gdal apps when launching from python subprocess.call or os.system

Comment: I would do the installs in a virtual environment such as with anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

[Boundless Desktop](https://boundlessgeo.com/boundless-desktop/) contains its own version of [GDAL/OGR](https://connect.boundlessgeo.com/docs/desktop/1.0.0/components/gdal_ogr.html) and has its own command shell to execute commands. The conflict exists with ArcGIS.